# I am trying to redirect my page through header function but it will not work rather my query is working ...why?

Tags: php

This is my index file:

```
session_start();
include_once 'conn.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['hell'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentreg WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['password']==$pass)
    {
        $_SESSION['hell']=$row['stu_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "hello"."<br/>";
        echo $row['password']."<br/>";
        echo $row['qualification'];
    }
}
```

This is my home file:

```
session_start();
include_once 'conn.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['hell']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentreg WHERE stu_id = ".$_SESSION['hell']);
$sturow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "welcome";
```

It will not work rather my query is working …why?

Comment: Hi Suraj, Can you please format your code and question? It will help others in answering your question.

Comment: In general, you should avoid mysql_* functions. rest you enable error mode and check the error.

Comment: Code is badly formatted! This is a problem for you and for those trying to help you.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message? Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at top of page to check.

Maybe there was text printed before the header not letting it redirect?

Are there spaces before the php opening tag?

Is session variable hell exist from another page?

Comment: That will let you check to see if there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

You add this line at start the page

```
ob_start();
```

and you add the this code after header function

```
exit;
```

Comment: it doesnt work it returns the query result but not redirecting to home.php.

Comment: you  have teamviewer ?

Comment: ok here working fine for me. if you password stored md5 format or normal ?

Comment: and show example database password and you entered password

Comment: everything is working. ..query returns the values from database as shown in else part of index.php but after dat it is going in else part instead of if part where i used session variable and header function.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
echo "<script>window.location='home.php'</script>";
```

Comment: Yeah ... I don't think this randomly inserting JavaScript will help the OP much here...